# Electron built app package has empty style.css

Tags: webpack, electron, electron-builder, electron-react-boilerplate

I am using `electron-react-boilerplate` with tailwind and my `config.renderer.prod.ts` looks like this:

```js
import path from 'path';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';
import MiniCssExtractPlugin from 'mini-css-extract-plugin';
import { BundleAnalyzerPlugin } from 'webpack-bundle-analyzer';
import CssMinimizerPlugin from 'css-minimizer-webpack-plugin';
import { merge } from 'webpack-merge';
import TerserPlugin from 'terser-webpack-plugin';
import baseConfig from './webpack.config.base';
import webpackPaths from './webpack.paths';
import checkNodeEnv from '../scripts/check-node-env';
import deleteSourceMaps from '../scripts/delete-source-maps';

checkNodeEnv('production');
deleteSourceMaps();

const configuration: webpack.Configuration = {
  devtool: 'source-map',

  mode: 'production',

  target: [
    'web',
    'electron-renderer'
  ],

  entry: [path.join(webpackPaths.srcRendererPath, 'index.tsx')],

  output: {
    path: webpackPaths.distRendererPath,
    publicPath: './',
    filename: 'renderer.js',
    library: {
      type: 'umd',
    },
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.s?(a|c)ss$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: true,
              sourceMap: true,
              importLoaders: 1,
            },
          },
          'sass-loader',
        ],
        include: /\.module\.s?(c|a)ss$/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.s?(a|c)ss$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader',
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
            postcssOptions: {
              plugins:
                [
                  require('tailwindcss'),
                  require('autoprefixer'),
                ]
              },
            },
          },
        ],
        exclude: /\.module\.s?(c|a)ss$/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.s?(a|c)ss$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
        exclude: /\.module\.s?(c|a)ss$/,
      },
      // Fonts
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource',
      },
      // Images
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource',
      },
      // SVG
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: '@svgr/webpack',
            options: {
              prettier: false,
              svgo: false,
              svgoConfig: {
                plugins: [{ removeViewBox: false }],
              },
              titleProp: true,
              ref: true,
            },
          },
          'file-loader',
        ],
      },
    ],
  },

  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [new TerserPlugin(), new CssMinimizerPlugin()],
  },

  plugins: [
    /**
     * Create global constants which can be configured at compile time.
     *
     * Useful for allowing different behaviour between development builds and
     * release builds
     *
     * NODE_ENV should be production so that modules do not perform certain
     * development checks
     */
    new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin({
      NODE_ENV: 'production',
      DEBUG_PROD: false,
    }),

    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'style.css',
    }),

    new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({
      analyzerMode: process.env.ANALYZE === 'true' ? 'server' : 'disabled',
      analyzerPort: 8889,
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: path.join(webpackPaths.srcRendererPath, 'index.ejs'),
      minify: {
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeAttributeQuotes: true,
        removeComments: true,
      },
      isBrowser: false,
      isDevelopment: false,
    }),

    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.type': '"renderer"',
    }),
  ],
};

export default merge(baseConfig, configuration);
```

my `config.renderer.dev.ts` looks like this:

```js
import 'webpack-dev-server';
import path from 'path';
import fs from 'fs';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';
import chalk from 'chalk';
import { merge } from 'webpack-merge';
import { execSync, spawn } from 'child_process';
import ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin from '@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin';
import baseConfig from './webpack.config.base';
import webpackPaths from './webpack.paths';
import checkNodeEnv from '../scripts/check-node-env';

// When an ESLint server is running, we can't set the NODE_ENV so we'll check if it's
// at the dev webpack config is not accidentally run in a production environment
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  checkNodeEnv('development');
}

const port = process.env.PORT || 1212;
const manifest = path.resolve(webpackPaths.dllPath, 'renderer.json');
const skipDLLs =
  module.parent?.filename.includes('webpack.config.renderer.dev.dll') ||
  module.parent?.filename.includes('webpack.config.eslint');

/**
 * Warn if the DLL is not built
 */
if (
  !skipDLLs &&
  !(fs.existsSync(webpackPaths.dllPath) && fs.existsSync(manifest))
) {
  console.log(
    chalk.black.bgYellow.bold(
      'The DLL files are missing. Sit back while we build them for you with "npm run build-dll"',
    ),
  );
  execSync('npm run postinstall');
}

const configuration: webpack.Configuration = {
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',

  mode: 'development',

  target: [
    'web',
    'electron-renderer'
  ],

  entry: [
    `webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:${port}/dist`,
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    path.join(webpackPaths.srcRendererPath, 'index.tsx'),
  ],

  output: {
    path: webpackPaths.distRendererPath,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'renderer.dev.js',
    library: {
      type: 'umd',
    },
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.s?(c|a)ss$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: true,
              sourceMap: true,
              importLoaders: 1,
            },
          },
          'sass-loader',
        ],
        include: /\.module\.s?(c|a)ss$/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.s?css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader',
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
            postcssOptions: {
              plugins:
                [
                  require('tailwindcss'),
                  require('autoprefixer'),
                ]
              },
            },
          },
        ],
        exclude: /\.module\.s?(c|a)ss$/,
      },
      // {
      //   test: /\.s?css$/,
      //   use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      //   exclude: /\.module\.s?(c|a)ss$/,
      // },
      // Fonts
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource',
      },
      // Images
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource',
      },
      // SVG
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: '@svgr/webpack',
            options: {
              prettier: false,
              svgo: false,
              svgoConfig: {
                plugins: [{ removeViewBox: false }],
              },
              titleProp: true,
              ref: true,
            },
          },
          'file-loader',
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    ...(skipDLLs
      ? []
      : [
          new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
            context: webpackPaths.dllPath,
            manifest: require(manifest),
            sourceType: 'var',
          }),
        ]),

    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),

    /**
     * Create global constants which can be configured at compile time.
     *
     * Useful for allowing different behaviour between development builds and
     * release builds
     *
     * NODE_ENV should be production so that modules do not perform certain
     * development checks
     *
     * By default, use 'development' as NODE_ENV. This can be overriden with
     * 'staging', for example, by changing the ENV variables in the npm scripts
     */
    new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin({
      NODE_ENV: 'development',
    }),

    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      debug: true,
    }),

    new ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin(),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: path.join('index.html'),
      template: path.join(webpackPaths.srcRendererPath, 'index.ejs'),
      minify: {
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeAttributeQuotes: true,
        removeComments: true,
      },
      isBrowser: false,
      env: process.env.NODE_ENV,
      isDevelopment: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
      nodeModules: webpackPaths.appNodeModulesPath,
    }),
  ],

  node: {
    __dirname: false,
    __filename: false,
  },

  devServer: {
    port,
    compress: true,
    hot: true,
    headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
    static: {
      publicPath: '/',
    },
    historyApiFallback: {
      verbose: true,
    },
    setupMiddlewares(middlewares) {
      console.log('Starting preload.js builder...');
      const preloadProcess = spawn('npm', ['run', 'start:preload'], {
        shell: true,
        stdio: 'inherit',
      })
        .on('close', (code: number) => process.exit(code!))
        .on('error', (spawnError) => console.error(spawnError));

      console.log('Starting Main Process...');
      let args = ['run', 'start:main'];
      if (process.env.MAIN_ARGS) {
        args = args.concat(
          ['--', ...process.env.MAIN_ARGS.matchAll(/"[^"]+"|[^\s"]+/g)].flat(),
        );
      }
      spawn('npm', args, {
        shell: true,
        stdio: 'inherit',
      })
        .on('close', (code: number) => {
          preloadProcess.kill();
          process.exit(code!);
        })
        .on('error', (spawnError) => console.error(spawnError));
      return middlewares;
    },
  },
};

export default merge(baseConfig, configuration);
```

When I run `npm run package` the app doesnt show any styling.
`release/app/dist/renderer/style.css` is empty too.

The dev version via npm run start works fine tho.

My `App.tsx` has this at the top:
`import './App.css';`

and my App.css looks like so:

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
body {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
input{
  outline: none;
}
input:focus{
  outline: none;
}
.dragable {
  -webkit-app-region: drag;
}
.undragable {
  -webkit-app-region: no-drag;
}
```

The `.app` just shows a textarea and the text of the app. I followed exactly the [docs](https://electron-react-boilerplate.js.org/docs/styling/#tailwind-integration).

I think this problem is unrelated to tailwindcss. When I remove it from the `App.css` it should still atleast give me the other contents of the styling but `style.css` is still empty.

If anybody had this problem before and can help out it is greatly appreciated <3.